# What is the output destination of enscript by default?

Tags: printing, pdf

What is the output destination of enscript by default? I can't find it in the manpage of enscript.

I am trying to convert a text file to a pdf file, but don't know where it outputs the pdf file:

```
$ enscript -B -PPDF code/bloom.c 
lpr: No such file or directory
[ 2 pages * 1 copy ] sent to PDF
```

Note that I don't have a printer to connect to from my Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a manpage [here](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-enscript/).

**From The Command Line**

It looks like you just need to add the -p option:

```
enscript -B -PPDF code/bloom.c -p myfile.ps
```

*NOTE: enscript only makes postscipt files, read on to learn how to convert to pdf*

According to @PerlDuck:

> -PPDF sends the output to the printer named PDF, so I would drop that switch

Leaving us with this command:

```
enscript -B code/bloom.c -p myfile.ps
```

You can then convert the ps file to pdf with ghostscript:

```
sudo apt install ghostscript
ps2pdf myfile.ps myfile.pdf
```

**From GUI**

You can print any file to a pdf using the system print dialog.

Open the file you want to turn to a pdf in your favorite text editor (or whatever depending on the file) and print it (`CTRL+P`). From the CUPS print dialog -> destination, select print to file and you can make a PDF that way too.

Comment: `-PPDF` sends the output to the printer named `PDF`, so I would drop that switch.

Comment: @Perl with or without -PPDF, the output files are created the same. Not sure why it matters.

Comment: More interestingly, the output file is actually ps not pdf file, not sure why. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470364/how-shall-i-generate-a-pdf-file-instead-of-a-ps-file-using-enscript

Comment: @Tim Maybe `enscript` is the wrong tool. The manpage says its purpose is to generate PostScript, not PDF but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I updated answer so OP can end up with PDF after a couple more steps... but @PerlDuck has a great point... maybe just use the CUPS print dialog and select print to file

Comment: Thanks. So why does -PPDF  not create pdf file? Does it work on your ubuntu?

Comment: enscript only makes postscript files... see latest update to end up with PDF

Comment: if not using enscript, what command can do the work?

Comment: enscript is the right way to go, you just need to convert to PDF after, or use CUPS print dialog... all is contained in this answer